Zener diode 1N4733A exceeds Zener voltage
Trying to wire 1N4733A rated at 5.1 V with 49 mA current, however getting different results.
With just 10 mA I take 5.25 volts from the diode. With 37.5 mA (which is still lower then test current) it's becoming 5.43. I understand that Zener diodes have their tolerance, but I tried some others at 3.3 V and still getting way higher Zener voltage.
Schematic is very simple, simulator shows correct 5.143 V in this case, I'm getting 5.43 V.


What type of voltmeter are you using for the measurement? Have you tested it against a known voltage source?

Your circuit consumes 44 mA by my reckoning.

If you want a more stable Zener voltage with changes in current and temperature, use an IC emulated Zener diode such as the inexpensive TL431.  It can be programmed to any desired voltage (within its current and power limits) by two resistors.

Check the value of your resistor (measure it). Your measurement (if correct) is close to the expected voltage if R1 was 4.99Ω. Note that 49Ω is not a standard E24 or E96 value, which leads to doubt. (4.99Ω and 49.9Ω are standard E96 values).

@PeterSmith i have zt301, tested it couple times, never saw more than 0.01 V error

@Spehro'speff'Pefhany well it's 47 Ohm, but i did measure it, so actual resistance is 48.9 Ohm

@Alexander Excellent. That's a pretty high deviation (+4%). Usually even 5% resistors are closer than that. Is there a fresh battery in your meter?

This datasheet states that the measurements where made with this condition:

Based on DC measurement at thermal equilibrium while maintaining the lead temperature (TL) at 30 °C + 1 °C, 9.5 mm (3/8") from the
diode body

If you're not meeting that requirement then your readings may not match the datasheet. At 37.5 mA it will be dissipating somewhere around 200 mW, which may be heating it up enough to make \$V_Z\$ higher. You might try changing the temperature in the simulator to see what effect that has (if your simulator does that, I know LTspice does).

From the ON Semi Datasheet, there are two things worth mentioning. First, there is some variation allowed. Technically, when you are matching conditions, a Zener voltage of 5.355V is allowable at the test current of 49mA.

Second, you are causing the device to heat up considerably. The note at the top of the table says:

The zener voltage is measured with the device junction in the thermal
equilibrium at the lead temperature (TL) at 30C ± 1C and 3/8” lead
length.

At about 0.25W dissipation, you are probably well beyond 30C. That will likely increase the zener voltage, resulting in higher voltages than intended.
Finally, another possible source of error is not measuring the voltage across the diode directly. If you have marginal connections, a few extra Ohms could easily give you that voltage difference. Breadboard connections, for example, can have higher resistance than expected.
One final note, you don't need to run a Zener diode at it's test current, you can use a lower current instead. More current in most applications is just wasted power and extra heat.

Could temperature contribute that much? There is a temperature chart from the link you posted, it shows very tiny change of zener voltage, like 0.14% per 10 degrees.

@Alexander I would argue it's a contributing factor. I could see that diode getting pretty hot. That being said, high quality characterization data isn't readily available so it's hard to say how large of an effect there is. Temperature coefficients are rarely linear.

5.1V is close to the minimum tempco voltage for a Zener. Motorola specifies the range of  tempco of their 1N4733A as between about 0.1 and 1.5mV/K. If we take 0.8mV as typical , it would take 413°C rise to account entirely for the difference.


which is still lower then test current

The test current is pulsed. You're not supposed to run the diode at that current in normal use. It heats up too much. With temperature rise, the Zener voltage goes up too.
You'll find that at a much lower current - say 1mA - you'll get voltage similar to what you expect.
